# Microsoft Windows 10 pro reinstallation

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I am in the mist of fixing a installation problem. Originally, I had installed ubuntu 16.04 and booted in BIOS mode and everything works fine. Now, I am required to make a dual boot system with Windows 10 pro which uses UEFI. I had hardware and firmware supporting BIOS and UEFI so no problem on there.

I tried to do a fresh install of windows 10 pro as it was the recommended steps for dual boot system with ubuntu 16.04. This is where I encountered my problem and 2 methods I had tried.

**Method 1**

Created a bootable usb using "Create a recovery drive" option in Windows 10 pro from another workstation. This uses the "Recovery Media Creator" from Windows.

Reason: I currently have 2 identical Dell Precision 7820 Workstation, one is still in windows only and the other is with ubuntu only. Let call the one with windows **A** and ubuntu **B**.

I thought since there are the same make, model and from Dell, I could create a recovery usb from **A** and use it on **B**, so went ahead.

Problem: I put in my recovery drive, boot from usb (in UEFI mode) and start the recovery, choosing the fully clean recovery option. The installation process is got stuck for several hours in 7% and I had to do a hard reset.

**Method 2**

Created a bootable usb using "Media Creation Tools" from Windows

Problem: Using this option, I could not detect the drive during installation.
I booted in UEFI mode.

I suspect that its because my original ubuntu drive cannot boot in UEFI mode and i might have to do the clean reinstallation in BIOS mode. Also, my SATA setting is RAID on so that maybe an issue too. What should I do next and what setups should I take?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows has a "Reset This PC" in Control Panel, negating the need to reinstall. Granted it's maybe not as clean and any Dual boot menu may be lost.

I believe you need to boot in BIOS mode to see BIOS drives correctly on installation. and vica-versa.

**How I install a dual boot system in UEFI**

1: Install WIndows in UEFI from USB.

2: Use [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) (UEFI version) In windows to create an Ubuntu Live USB and install/re-partition from there.

A windows ISO can also be added to the YUMI USB and booted from there, you choose which to boot during startup. I generally have several OS's on one 32GB stick.

IF You want to keep an existing OS which is BIOS boot then when you choose a device to boot to from BIOS; a USB stick will sometimes have 2 listings, one prefixed with **UEFI: **, the one without is BIOS boot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. YUMI looks good! I will give it a try

Comment: quick question, It does matter whether I would install from the drive created by method 1 or method 2 right?

Comment: 1 then 2 I meant. windows is best installed first as it overwrites the Grub menu. You could partition using Gparted from a Live USB Ubuntu before everything.. but windows likes to make it's own partitions as UEFI mode

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Got this working. So apparently, method 2 was not possible as I could not detect my hard drive whether I boot in UEFI or BIOS mode. I even change the setting of SATA to AHCI and still wasnt able to.

I thought I would give method 1 another try, this time with BIOS mode boot + SATA in AHCI and boot from my recovery usb drive. And it booted successfully!!!

I was able to recover my drive back to its original state when I got the workstation! So apparently the last time it was stuck, the application is still running, just that I didnt had the patience to wait it out. Lesson Learnt!